# How to make backBarButton work in modal presentation?

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I need to present second VC modally. At first the nav bar did not appear on second vc, so I did the following: add new Nav controller, set presentation to be full screen. Like shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9hJn.jpg
Then I choose navigation item in second VC and type a name for a back button [image]

Then the button appears in Navigation Item and I drag it to View Controller
[image]

All in all it looks like this:
[image]

The problem is: the back button does not take me back when I run the app, it does nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segues are generally used to go forward (unless you use unwind segues). Since you want to go back, you should create an `IBAction` in the `ViewController` with the back button. Then link the back button to this `IBAction` and dismiss the `ViewController` in the method body

```
@IBAction func btnBackPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: Glad to be of help